# How to open other mobile apps on press in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am looking for an easy way to open apps, Facebook and Instagram specifically, on a button press from my React Native app. It should also check if the app is installed on the device first, and open the app store if it isn't. It needs to work on both iOS and Android. I am a beginner so if you can post an example it would help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Linking** module of react-native to open other mobile apps.

```
import { Linking } from "react-native";

    const APP_ID = //ID of app need to open in play store
    const appDeepLinkURL = //Most of the mobile app provide it 
     Linking.openURL(appDeepLinkURL).catch(err => {
          Linking.openURL(
            `market://details?id=${APP_ID}`
          ).catch(err => Linking.openURL(
            `http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=${APP_ID}`
          ).catch(err => console.error("An error occurred", err)););
        });
```

Similarly, you can do for the iOS,
you can refer to the official doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/linking.html).

Comment: it's doesn't work with Google Maps App other apps it's work very well, any idea?

Comment: @DevA are you using correct ID  `com.google.android.apps.maps`

Comment: @Harshkurra how to get App_Id and appDeepLinkURL for the other application?

Comment: If it is a famous App then you will get the correct ID through google search else you have to some reverse-engineering

Answer (score 1):

use react-native **`Linking`** Component

```
import { 
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
  Linking,

} from 'react-native';

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => { Linking.openURL('sms:' + {contactNumber} 
 + '?body=Hi'); }}>
 <Text> Open Message App </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: it's doesn't work with Google Maps App other apps it's work very well, any idea?